Novel in which the MC uses dragon blood on a group of koi/carp and finally selects the surviving one as his first soul
I read this novel way before, it features a world where the people needs to absorb the soul of other creatures at the start of their cultivation and the protagonist selects a koi/carp as his first soul, because he knows that koi/ carp can further evolve into a dragon. because he is a reincarnated person.
I also remember that the MC gets his first skill is something related to bubbles, because the fish likes to blow bubbles.
